# Analytic geometry, circles

Tags: analytic-geometry, circles

The center of a circle is on the line $2x+3y=4$. The circle is tangent to the line $x-3y=8$, at point $(11,1)$. Find the equation of the circle in general form.

Comment: What is the tangent perpendicular to? Can you find the center?

Answer (score 0):

The perpendicular line to $x-3y=8 \iff y=\frac13x-\frac83$ is $y_p=-3x+b$, which must pass through the point $(11,1)$, hence: $y_p=-3x+34$.

The intersection of the lines is the center of the circle:
$$\begin{cases} y_p=-3x+34 \\ y=-\frac23x+\frac43\end{cases} \Rightarrow (x,y)=(14,-8).$$
Hence:
$$(x-14)^2+(y+8)^2=(14-11)^2+(-8-1)^2=90.$$

Comment: I don't think you should answer "homework dump" questions that show no effort.

Comment: @Dylan, you are right, though the OP still needs to understand and justify the steps of the solution and answer several "why?" questions...